# Yet Another MVVM question... Is my understanding correct?

Tags: mvvm

Sorry if this is a duplicate, It's not so much 'What is MVVM' though, but rather, 'Is this MVVM', I've read quite a bit, and think I've got a basic understanding of what it is, I've got my own 'one-liner', as such, on how I interpret it, but want to make sure it's correct before I firmly ingrain it in my head,

Essentially; The Model is pure data - no methods, there is one ViewModel per Model, it holds a reference to the Model - it performs all changes to the Models data and finally the View will hold one (or more) ViewModel reference(s) and format & display the data provided by the ViewModel.

(Not after links to tutorials, blogs etc, just a yes, or no with tweaks will be fine, as I'll have to re-read everything again anyway if not :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not completely - at least, not as I would completely define it.

The Model does not have to be pure data.  The model is the portion of your application that is completely domain specific, and has no "presentation related" information.

This will typically include all of the domain specific data, but also potentially methods that are pure business logic, and data access, etc.  Anything specific to the business logic and processes, and not part of the "display", is part of the model.

Also, although "one ViewModel per Model" is the most common form of working, there are times when you may expose a "model" class through multiple ViewModels.  This can be useful, for example, if you are trying to expose only part of a model to your designer, as it allows you to make a smaller ViewModel class.  The ViewModel adapts the model for work with the View - if the entire Model is not required, this adapter can be made smaller (and more easily testable, maintainable, etc) by only working with the portion required.

Personally, I prefer to think in terms of "one ViewModel per View", as the ViewModel can adapt one or more models in order to work appropriately with a given View, but even then, sometimes it's helpful to swap out a ViewModel within the same View in order to change content.

Answer (score 4):

Close, but not quite.  Here are some points that are are different than yours:

1. Models can have methods on them.  They are not just data.  They might have methods like "retrieve", "store", etc.  Business logic code.  View agnostic.
2. There is no restriction to how many ViewModels hold a reference to the Model.  ViewModels encapsulate view-level behavior, so you may have many different sets of behavior for the same model.  For example, one ViewModel might be a read-only transformation of a model item.  Another might provide read/write form validation on the same model item.
3. There can be more than one ViewModel per view, based on the behavior you want.  For example, you might include "premium content" behavior with one ViewModel and "free content" behavior with another ViewModel but maintain the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes.  Practically, not really.  Best practice is always to reduce dependencies and split up your responsibilities among classes on a 1:1 basis, but you'll find IRL situations where it isn't as easy to be a MVC purist.

I think the best attitude is to do your best, then document the rest.  Don't sweat purity too much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of great information here, and I think that most of these answers are right.  I don't think there is any 1 specific definition, nor is there 1 specific authority on this matter.  Even microsoft does not really have clear definition on this.

The one item I would add which is not in the name of MVVM, but is common to all implementations of MVVM that I am familiar with.  This is a Messaging or Notification system, which seems to always be linked as a platform for the ViewModel.  Messaging just notifies the View Models when things change which may affect others.  A good implementation of this in mind allows View Models and Views to both be agnostic about things they do not directly bind to by using generic notification messages.

The benefit of the entire pattern in my opinion is to make you application with modular, swappable parts with as little type-dependency as possible.

This is a real missing part in my mind, as it provides the same benefits / functions that you gain from separate controller logic in the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty close. Except it is not correct to say that the Model is only pure data. It can and should contain methods for performing the various use cases against it.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong.
You can have several Models and all of them could have their own Views and then be a part of a single ViewModel.
Example:
You have the Models: Product, Customer
Each of them have their own View represented as a Custom Control
And you have a ViewModel which combines all your models and finally on the window of your app you combine all together your Views which talk to your Models via your ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this. The Model is your system, the meat and veg of what the system does. The only considerations it has is how to do it's job, not how it is going to be used. It exposes events, attributes and methods defined at the system level, but it has no concept of what will be pressing it's buttons (or if it even has buttons!). It does not try to format data to a more user friendly format, it formats its data in a model friendly way.

---

The view model is the UX (user experience). It defines how you are going to use the system. It defines (through public commands and attributes) user orientated access into the system. It is the bridge that the user will use to enter the system. It binds onto the events of the model, and through it's commands, it will provide access into the models functionality.

It should handle validation, (is that age a sensible age?) retrieve data, converting and caching of records whilst they are being displayed. So, for example, you're looking at a patient record, the viewmodel gets the data from the model, and caches it internally, then publishes this to the view. What happens if the model announces an update to that data? Throw the cached data away? what if you've edited it? This is all up to you, and this behavior should be defined in the view model.

The view model is a "contract" of what functionality and data is exposed to the user (through the view). The view model has no concept of HOW it is going to be displayed or interacted with. Commands should be named at a functional level, such as RefreshList, NOT MouseClickHandler.

---

Finally, the View. This is simply a visible representation of what is in the view model. Buttons and menus etc bind onto commands. Fields bind onto attributes and will update automatically through the magic of binding.

If you ever see yourself doing : "text1.text = value" you're doing it wrong. If you ever find yourself writing a command handler that says "my.ViewModel.SomeCommand" you're doing it wrong.